# Grab tags in a string with PHP/laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using PHP/Laravel 8 and I am trying to grab each tag (word who begins with #) of a string and edit the string to set an anchor inside it.

For example:

`$string = "Hello, this is a #string with multiples #tags";`

//method

=>
`$newString = "Hello, this is a <a href='/string'>#string</a> with multiples <a href='/tags' >#tags</a>"`

I tried a lot of things but I'm stuck since a moment...

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Ok, so show us your best attempt. It helps us understand the question

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace()`

```
#[^ ]+
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/S5ltfI/1)

```
$string = "Hello, this is a #string with multiples #tags";

echo preg_replace('/#([^ ]+)/', '<a href="/$1">$0</a>', $string);
```